# Changing text in splashscreen

Tags: vb.net, timer, splash-screen

I have created a splashscreen in VB.Net and everythings works perfect except the fact that I would like to change the loading text with multiple texts who changes every x seconds during the loading.

[image: Loading Text]

Exemple : `Dim LoadingTexts As String = {"charging 1...", "charging 2...", "info1..."}`

I have no idea how i can do this apart the fact that i surely have to use a timer... But how ?

Actual code:

```
Public Class frmSplashScreen
   Private stringTable() As String = {"Shovelling coal into the server...", "Programming the flux capacitor...", _
                                      "Searching for answer to live, the universe and everything...",
                                      "Waiting for Godot...", "Starting..."}
   Private stringMove As Integer = 0

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub ProcessCommand(ByVal cmd As System.Enum, ByVal arg As Object)
        MyBase.ProcessCommand(cmd, arg)
    End Sub

    Public Enum SplashScreenCommand
        SomeCommandId
    End Enum

    Public Sub SplashTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SplashTimer.Tick
        Me.SplashTimer.Enabled = False

        Me.labelStarting.Text = stringTable(stringMove)
        Me.labelStarting.Refresh()

        stringMove += 1
        If stringMove < stringTable.Length Then Me.SplashTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks.

Comment: change the `Text` property of the `Starting...` label with a timer. Don't forget to call `DoEvents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a timer,progress bar,button and label,with the progress bar's step value set to 10,your code may look something like this:

`Public Class Form1`

```
Private Sub butStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butStart.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(ProgressBar1.Step) 'use method below as well
    'ProgressBar1.Value+=ProgressBar1.Step


    Me.Refresh()

    If ProgressBar1.Value >= 0 AndAlso ProgressBar1.Value < 35 Then
        Label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & "% Starting"
        Me.Refresh()
    ElseIf ProgressBar1.Value >= 35 AndAlso ProgressBar1.Value < 75 Then
        Label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & "% Mid value"
        Me.Refresh()
    ElseIf ProgressBar1.Value >= 75 AndAlso ProgressBar1.Value < 100 Then
        Label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & "% Finishing"
        Me.Refresh()
    ElseIf ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        'Move to next form or something
    End If
End Sub
```

`End Class`

Comment: BTW,if this answer works for you please dont forget to check it as your accepted answer or whatever. and also just drag the timer on the form,add an interval period and double click it to access its Tick event

Comment: Thanks for your help but my progressbar is turning in cycles and not from 0 to 100. There is no beginning and no end to it except to loading of my WindowsForm.

Comment: check that the minimum value property is set to 0 and maximum set to 100 and everytime u open the form you set the value to zero eg `ProgressBar1.Value =0` in the form load event or something

Comment: I Used a mix between your both solutions and it worked thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to change every X seconds, then use a Timer. Change the `.Text` property of the label:

```
Dim iLoadText As Integer = 0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False

    Label1.Text = LoadingTexts(iLoadText)
    Label1.Refresh()

    iLoadText += 1
    If iLoadText < LoadingTexts.Length Then Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What its not working? Is throwing an error? Not doing nothing? Have you started the Timer already? (by default is `Enabled = False`)

Comment: Sorry I posted my code to give more details. My timer is by default on `Enabled = True`
What doesn't is that it stays on `"Starting..."`
I gonna try with `Console.Writeline` to see if the timer is ok

Comment: Nothing neither with `Console.writeline`